# Mysql insert multiple rows with random values

Tags: mysql

Hello i am trying insert 100-200 new rows to user_acc table , but for some reason my current code do nothing .

```
DELIMITER //
DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;

 WHILE x < 200 DO
INSERT INTO `user_acc`(`playRegion`, `firsttimelogin`) VALUES
(RAND() * (6)+1,1) ;
SET x = x +1;
 END WHILE;
DELIMITER ;
```

so i am adding playRegion and firsttimelogin for each of row , playRegion is random 1-5 and firstimelogin is walways 1. once i try to execute query nothing happens no error nothing .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative with a stored proc that uses `Loop`:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
  test_loop : LOOP
      IF (int_val = 10) THEN
      LEAVE test_loop;
    END IF;
   INSERT INTO `user_acc`(`playRegion`, `firsttimelogin`) VALUES
   (RAND() * (6)+1,1) ;
    SET int_val = int_val +1;
  END LOOP; 
END;

call proc_loop_test;

select * from `user_acc`;
```

I limited to 10 just for testing

[Functional Example](http://rextester.com/SAJXX26044) that you can play around with

[Credit for this solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62812/how-to-do-while-loops)

Comment: @EgiDijus elaborate, check the link to rextester, works fine

Comment: you can save stored proc using WorkBench but otherwise use delimiters if running from shell.  You can't run anonymous block, need stored proc

Answer (score 0):

[DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html)

> **DECLARE** is permitted only inside a **BEGIN ... END** compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does that excerpt from the documentation resolve the given problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to execute an anonymous code block, which MySQL does not support.

You could create a named stored procedure to execute that code.

Rather than implement your own stored procedure, my suggestion is to use the [`mysqlslap`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlslap.html) utility, which makes it easy to generate test data.

This command should work for you:

```
mysqlslap --iterations 200 \
  --create-schema=test \
  --query="INSERT INTO user_acc(playRegion, firsttimelogin) VALUES (RAND() * (6)+1,1) ;"
```

Comment: syntax error at line 1 1064 , and i am using 5.6 if thats have to do anything with it

Comment: You need to run `mysqlslap` in your shell, not at the mysql command line.

Comment: trying to run shell but none of my passwords are right